# i am trying to do a simple update with php but not working

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to do a simple update with php but not working, i tried echoing out the value which worked well but when querying it it does not update in the database

```
if(isset($_POST['sva_change'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $phone_num = $_POST['pnum'];
    $bank_name = $_POST['bname'];
    $accountname = $_POST['aname'];
    $acountnumber = $_POST['anum'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];



    $query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE general_users SET hemail = '$email', u_name = '$username', phone_num = '$phone_num', bank_name = '$bank_name', account_name = '$accountname', account_number = '$acountnumber' where _userid='$id'");

    echo $email, $username, $phone_num, $bank_name, $accountname, $acountnumber;

if($query) {
    echo "Succcessfully Updated";
} else {
    echo "Erorr while updating record : ";
}

$DBcon->close();

}else{
    echo "errorr rr r r ";
}

?>
```

Comment: print the mysql errors and see

Comment: Please just use prepared statements or bindings.

Comment: You have column Names starting with underscore? `_userid`?

Comment: Take a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn something about SQL injections. Your code is not save at all and your database could be hacked in a few seconds without any need of know-how.

Comment: do not directly save posted variables from your html form. Please tell me this is not in production!!

Comment: @Akin You would cry if you would know how many websites actually uses exact this type of code in prodution...

Comment: yeah! @Twinfriends this just gives PHP a bad reputation

Comment: @Akin Yes. Thats exactly why you read everywhere that PHP is the biggest bullshit ever... simply because you can write really unsave code and nobody cares about. I fell in love with PHP years ago and I still think its one of the most powerfull languages to develop.. if written the right way. So happy to find other people who has the same opinion

Comment: Yeah true that @Twinfriends. Like they say, you can write good code in any language and bad code in any language

Answer (score 0):

A good think to do to know if the query failed or just the php is printing the query on the screen, copy it and paste it on phpmyadmin (or other). 
If the row is added in your table, then you have an issue with your php. Else, Phpmyadmin will show you where is the issue. For example, maybe you try to save a string or float in an `int` column.

You can enable mysql erros too to see where is the issue, that's quite precise and in 90% of cases, you will find which value or colunm has an issue.

By the way, your script is very unsecure: I can inject what I want, and drop your table if you want in few seconds with SQL injections.
Use prepared statement: **Never insert in a table without check in server side**

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php